# How to setup a Bearer Token Authentication in AsyncOAuth2Client with authlib

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, authlib, httpx

I'm calling an API that has a bearer token authentication.
With regular `requests` package I have successfully implemented it, but then I had to upgrade the class to run concurrent requests.

I found `authlib.integrations.httpx_client.AsyncOAuth2Client` to have the OAuth2 piece, and then `authlib.oauth2.rfc6750.BearerTokenValidator` to have the Bearer token piece.
But then I'm not able to run it correctly.

In the meantime I did try `aiohttp`, but moved to `httpx` since it seemed better with the OAuth2 authentication.
Still, my first time meeting `asyncio`, `httpx` and friends, so all suggestions are welcome.

The successful part with `requests` comes first:

```py
class BearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase): 
  def __init__(self, token): 
    self.token = token
 
  def __call__(self, a_request): 
    a_request.headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {self.token}'
    return a_request 


class MySession(Session): 
  def __init__(self): 
    super().__init__()
    self.set_token()

  def set_token():
    auth_enc = encode64('{username}:{password}'.format(**access_dict))
    the_headers = {'Authorization': f'Basic {auth_enc}'}
    auth_resp = self.post(AUTH_URL, headers=the_headers)
    self.token = the_resp.json()

  def call_api(self): 
    for _ in range(tries): 
      a_resp = self.get(API_URL, auth=BearerAuth(self.token['access_token']))
      if a_resp.status_code == 401: 
        self.set_token()
        continue
      elif a_resp.status_code == 200:
        return a_resp
    else: 
      return None
```

The unsuccessful part with `AsyncOauth2Client` is next:

```py
class AsyncBearerAuth(BearerTokenValidator): 
  def __init__(self, token): 
    self.token = token

  def authenticate_token(self, token): 
    return token

  def __call__(self, a_request): 
    a_request.headeers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {self.token}'
    return a_request


class MyAsynClient(AsyncOAuth2Client): 
  def __init__(self): 
    AsyncOAuth2Client.__init__(self, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET)
    # self.create_authorization_url(AUTH_URL)

  async def set_token(self): 
    auth_data = { 'grant_type' : 'password', 
                  'username'   : AUTH_USERNAME, 
                  'password'   : AUTH_PASSWORD } } }
    self.token = await self.fetch_token(AUTH_URL, **auth_data)

  async def call_api(self): 
    if not hasattr(self, 'token'): 
      await self.set_token()

    for _ in range(tries): 
      the_resp = await self.get(API_URL, 
            auth=AsyncBearerAuth(self.token['access_token']))
      
      if the_resp.status_code == 401: 
        await self.set_token()
        continue
      elif the_resp.status_code == 200: 
        return the_resp 

    else: 
      return None

def main(): 
   async with MyAsyncClient() as client: 
     the_tasks = []
     for _ in range(10): 
       a_task = asyncio.create_task( client.call_api() )
       the_tasks.append(a_task)
     results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

   do_something(results)
```

The error lies in this piece:

```
     the_resp = await self.get(API_URL, 
            auth=AsyncBearerAuth(self.token['access_token']))
```

and it says:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py in _send_single_request(self, request)
   1683         Sends a single request, without handling any redirections.
   1684         """
-> 1685         transport = self._transport_for_url(request.url)
   1686         timer = Timer()
   1687         await timer.async_start()
```

And if I remove the '**call**' from `AsyncBearerAuth` the error that I get is:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_auth.py in auth_flow(self, request)
    113
    114     def auth_flow(self, request: Request) -> typing.Generator[Request, Response, None]:
--> 115         yield self._func(request)
    116
    117

TypeError: __call__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'scope' and 'request'
```

Other questions that I didn't fully understand are:

- Am I right in inheriting from `BearerTokenValidator`?
  I'm following the documentation on [Bearer Token Usage](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/resource-server.html#flask-oauth2-resource-protector) but I'm not sure about the Validator object here.
- I have also tried commenting and uncommenting the `create_authorization_url` with no success.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve this? I am facing the same problem, with requests works but auth header with httpx does not work. Thank you in advance